How to prevent punctuation marks (dots, commas) from going to new line?
How to stop commas, dots, brackets, etc. from going to new line?
They need to stay on the same line with the content that is immediately before them.
The svg is inserted with jQuery after the document is loaded. Maybe that's the problem? Anyway - is there a way to fix this? This happens at certain widths only, of course.
The HTML is this:


<li><a href="https://www.3td.lv/lv/ebooks" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="display: inline;">“3td&nbsp;e-GRĀMATU bibliotēka”<svg class="icon-external-link" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none">
  <path d="M15.75 6.75L15.75 2.25M15.75 2.25H11.25M15.75 2.25L9.75 8.25M7.5 3.75H5.85C4.58988 3.75 3.95982 3.75 3.47852 3.99524C3.05516 4.21095 2.71095 4.55516 2.49524 4.97852C2.25 5.45982 2.25 6.08988 2.25 7.35V12.15C2.25 13.4101 2.25 14.0402 2.49524 14.5215C2.71095 14.9448 3.05516 15.289 3.47852 15.5048C3.95982 15.75 4.58988 15.75 5.85 15.75H10.65C11.9101 15.75 12.5402 15.75 13.0215 15.5048C13.4448 15.289 13.789 14.9448 14.0048 14.5215C14.25 14.0402 14.25 13.4101 14.25 12.15V10.5" stroke="#FF6F00" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
</svg></a>&nbsp;(Piekļuves dati ir Siguldas novada bibliotēkā izsniegtais lietotāja vārds un parole. E-grāmatu lietošanas noteikumi aplūkojami&nbsp;<a href="https://www.sigulda.lv/public/download.php?id=4961" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="display: inline;">šeit<svg class="icon-external-link" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none">
  <path d="M15.75 6.75L15.75 2.25M15.75 2.25H11.25M15.75 2.25L9.75 8.25M7.5 3.75H5.85C4.58988 3.75 3.95982 3.75 3.47852 3.99524C3.05516 4.21095 2.71095 4.55516 2.49524 4.97852C2.25 5.45982 2.25 6.08988 2.25 7.35V12.15C2.25 13.4101 2.25 14.0402 2.49524 14.5215C2.71095 14.9448 3.05516 15.289 3.47852 15.5048C3.95982 15.75 4.58988 15.75 5.85 15.75H10.65C11.9101 15.75 12.5402 15.75 13.0215 15.5048C13.4448 15.289 13.789 14.9448 14.0048 14.5215C14.25 14.0402 14.25 13.4101 14.25 12.15V10.5" stroke="#FF6F00" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
</svg></a>.)</li>



Expected output:

Current output:

I tried break-word, white-space CSS properties with different values, I tried display CSS properties with different values, nothing helped.

At my end it does not go in the new line, did you check in different browsers, and screens?

Put a span around the characters you want to remain together. Give that span CSS that includes white-space: nowrap.

Perhaps have a look at text-wrap: balance ?
